# Package Manager Console Automation using DTE in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build-automation

I am trying to automate the Package Manager Console window in Visual Studio 2012. I am DTE object to achieve the same. By using below code line I am able to open the Package Manager Console window.

`DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.PackageManagerConsole");`

Now I want to pass few parameter to this window. Basically below parameter
 I want to pass

`add-migration 'migrationName'`

I also want to pass the default project name to the PMC window.

Please help me to achieve this functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way for running a script in package manager console is parameter passing into it.

```
var script = "function global:SaveAll {write-host \"All files saved.\"} SaveAll";
_ObjDTE.ExecuteCommand("View.PackageManagerConsole", script);
```